# Show cpu usage with bash script and print in txt file

Tags: bash

I have a question.

I need to do a bash script command that show me CPU usage and stamp in an external txt file.

Have some idea? Thank all so much!

Comment: BTW, what is your idea on this?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux) to see how to obtain the CPU usage. You'll just need to put it on a script, then you can run such as: `./cpuUsage.sh > cpu.txt`.

Comment: Im running a script with some xterm. I need to calculate the cpu usage and print it into a text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sysstat` as suggested in the comments or stick with (probably installed already) `top`. Example from my system (you can of course grep out a specific field if needed):

```
$ top -bn 1 | sed -n '3p'
%Cpu(s): 16.4 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id,  1.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
```

You can add the timestamp with `date`:

```
$ date
Thu Nov  1 19:46:15 MSK 2012
```

Comment: ok its work. How can i print this out in txt file with bash?
Thank you so mucH!

Comment: @NikM Just add a _redirection_ in the end (`>> log.txt` for example).

Comment: Yes its work:) Sorry i have used 2> and doesnt work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The top version and sysstat never worked for me. This did:

```
ps -A -o pcpu | tail -n+2 | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: @jangorecki `sudo apt-get install bc`