# Making a simple system monitor bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a simple bash script to monitor the following: CPU Utilization, outbound network bandwidth, and inbound network bandwidth. The kicker, I have to use information from /proc/loadavg for the CPU and information from /proc for the bandwidth.

For the CPU Utilization, because it is supposed to be on a short time interval, I can use the first value from /proc/loadavg. Thing is, I'm not sure how to just get that one value so what I have so far is this:

```
CPU=sudo cat /proc/loadavg | sed 's///'
echo "CPU Utilization: $CPU %"
```

Where I'm not sure what the sed operation should be. Also I'm not sure how to format what I would get from that so that it would print as "16.5%"

For the bandwidth monitors I haven't the slightest clue of what I could use in /proc to get that sort of information so I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Load average

You don't need `sudo` to read `/proc/loadavg`

In addition, `sed` is the wrong tool here, try using `cut`, for example:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 < /proc/loadavg
0.04
```

`cut` will cut lines by a delimiter (given with `-d`), in this case a space, and you can then use `-f` to select a field, in this case the first one.

Now, converting it to percentages is actually fairly meaningless, since you'll often end up above 100% (see comment below), I've seen load averages in excess of 50 (that would be 5000% percent?).
In all my years of UNIX/Linux experience, I can't recall ever seeing the load average being expressed as a percentage, and if I would encounter such a thing, I would find it *very* odd.

But if you *really* want to (you don't!), just multiply by 100 with `dc`, like so:

```
$ dc -e "`cut -d' ' -f1 < /proc/loadavg` 100 * p"
29.00
```

> For the CPU Utilization, because it is supposed to be on a short time
>   interval, I can use the first value from /proc/loadavg.

The load average is **not** the same thing as CPU usage.

- A load average of 1 means there is one process waiting for *something* (usually the CPU or disk).
- A load average of 2 means there are two processes waiting.
- A load average of 0.5 (over the last minute), *can* mean that for 30 seconds, there was one process waiting, and for 30 seconds, there were no processes waiting. It can *also* mean that for 15 seconds there were two processes waiting, and for 45 seconds there were no processes waiting. The keyword here is **average**.

If you want to get the CPU utilization, then this is probably the most portable way:

```
$ top -bn2 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
           tail -n1 | \
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
           awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
```

Note you need to use `-n2` to get fairly accurate results.

I've adapted this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux), which also lists some other possibilities, some simpler, but most tools mentioned aren't installed by default on most systems.

### Network

> For the bandwidth monitors I haven't the slightest clue of what I
>   could use in /proc to get that sort of information so I'm open to all
>   suggestions.

You can use the output of `ifconfig`, for example, on my system:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.28  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 2001:980:82cd:1:20c:29ff:fe9e:c84b  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe9e:c84b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:9e:c8:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 45891  bytes 36176865 (34.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20802  bytes 2603821 (2.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It's the RX packets & TX packets we want. Let's extract just those values:

```
$ ifconfig ens33 | grep -E '(R|T)X packets' | grep -Eo '\([0-9].*\)' | tr -d '()'
34.5 MiB
2.5 MiB
```

- First we `grep` all the lines starting with RX or TX
- With those lines, we then `grep` for a parenthesis `\(`, followed by a number `[0-9]`, followed by *any* characters `.*`, followed by a closing parenthesis `\`). With the `-o` flag we show only the matching part, instead of the whole line.
- With `tr`, we remove the unwanted parentheses.

This should be what you want. If you want to get a number of bytes, you can use a different `grep` pattern in the second grep. I'll leave it as an exercise to you what exactly that is.

Comment: +1; nice job; so is there a [fairly easily scriptable] way to get a _CPU utilization percentage_ figure? Is there a way to use `\proc` to get bandwidth figures, as the OP suggests?

Comment: @mklement0 I'm not aware of anything in `/proc` that gets the bandwidth usage, and for completion's sake I've updated my answer regarding the CPU utilization.

Comment: Thanks; the CPU utilization code doesn't work as intended; if you use `-n2`, you'll get *two* output lines from the `grep` command, so I presume you only meant use the second. Also, the command appears to be written for systems where `top -v` returns `procps-ng` (e.g., Fedora). There's also `procps`, found on, e.g., Ubuntu and CentOS, where the command doesn't work (always indicates 100%, because parsing fails due to the line with the CPU figures being formatted differently). (cont'd below)

Comment: Here's a version that works on both implementations: `top -b -n2 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' '{ split($1, vs, " "); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%.1f%%\n", 100 - v }'`

Comment: @mklement0 Oops, I forgot to copy/paste the `tail` I used in testing >.< ... Also, wasn't aware of different `top` versions in Linux, thanks! You should post your solution to [the question I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux).

Comment: Minor update to the above - when the CPU is reported as 100% idle, the above command doesn't work; here's the corrected version: `top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can print the first number output by `cat /proc/loadavg` as a percent value (but see @Carpetsmoker's caveat regarding whether that makes sense), rounded to 1 decimal place:

```
 printf "1-minute load average: %.1f%%\n" \
   $(bc <<<"$(cut -d ' ' -f 1 /proc/loadavg) * 100")
```

Comment: Load average is *not* "CPU Utilization"! It is something fundamentally different.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Fair point - I was just reusing the OP's string and focusing on the calculation part - corrected to reflect what is actually being reported