# Remote PC CPU usage using python

Tags: python, remote-access, cpu-usage

I am using the following code to get remote PC CPU percentage of usage witch is slow and loading the remote PC because of SSHing.

```
per=(subprocess.check_output('ssh root@192.168.32.218 nohup python psutilexe.py',stdin=None,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)).split(' ')
print 'CPU %=',float(per[0])
print 'MEM %=',float(per[1])
```

where `psutilexe.py` is as follows:

```
import psutil
print psutil.cpu_percent(), psutil.virtual_memory()[2]
```

Would you please let me know if there is any alternate way to measure remote PC CPU % of usage using Python?

Comment: you can do  this by enabling SNMP on your host and read CPU/RAM informations using pysnmp on your remote host

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking look at Glances. It's written in python and can also be used for remote server monitoring:

https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

Using glances on remote server:

http://mylinuxbook.com/glances-an-all-in-one-system-monitoring-tool/

Comment: Second link is broken and takes you to some casino website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom Python script, since you can [have CPU usage directly with `top`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229692/240613), (or [with `sysstat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229396/240613), if installed).

Have you **profiled** your app? Is it the custom script which is making it slow, or the SSHing itself? If it's the SSHing, then:

- Consider logging once if you're getting multiple values, or:
- Consider using message queue instead of SSHing: monitored machines will constantly send their CPU usage to a message queue service, which will be listened by the machine which is in charge of gathering the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for it for a while and I think WMI does what you need.

[WMI_Python_Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/)

```
import wmi
pc = wmi.WMI('PC_Name')
cpu = pc.Win32_Processor()
for i in cpu:
    print (i.LoadPercentage)
```

Hopefully this is what you need.