# How can I replace 'bc' tool in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following command in my bash script:

```
printf '\n"runtime": %s' "$(bc -l <<<"($a - $b)")"
```

I need to run this script on around 100 servers and I have found that on few of them `bc` is not installed. I am not admin and cannot install `bc` on missing servers.

In that case, what alternative can i use to perform the same calculation?  Please let me know how the new command should look like

Comment: **Workaround** to use a subset of the bc functionality without installation: The init(cpio|ramfs|rd) mechanism of your distro should provide a busybox binary which is likely to have bc applet enabled. E.g. on Arch the package [linux](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/linux/) depends on [mkinitcpio-busybox](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/mkinitcpio-busybox/). The latter provides ``/usr/lib/initcpio/busybox``, and ``$ /usr/lib/initcpio/busybox bc <<<"33-22"`` yields ``11``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you need a solution which works for floating-point arithmetic you can always fall back to Awk.

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN { printf "\n\"runtime\": %s", a-b }' </dev/null
```

Putting the code in a `BEGIN` block and redirecting input from `/dev/null` is a common workaround for when you want to use Awk but don't have a file of lines to loop over, which is what it's really designed to do.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot the comma -- updated now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only dealing with integers you can use bash's [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) for this:

```
printf '\n"runtime": %s' $((a - b))
```

Note that this does assume you have bash available (as you've indicated you do). If you only have a stripped down Bourne shell (/bin/sh) arithmetic expansion is not available to you.

Comment: This presupposes that you have Bash or a similar shell on all the remote servers. The OP probably does (after all, they used `<<<here strings`) but it might still be worth pointing out.

Comment: @tripleee It felt like a safe assumption given that they tagged the question with `bash` and specifically said "bash script" in the title.

Comment: Sure, it's just that many visitors are probably baffled that "shell script" and "Bash script" are not necessarily synonymous. I'm thinking of future visitors more than the OP.

Comment: @tripleee Fair enough

Comment: Inside the arithmetic context you don't actually need the dollar signs before the variables `a` and `b`

Comment: Now that I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: `$((..))` is POSIX, so that's not a problem. I'd be more worried about having to support non-integers