# How to capture CPU idle time (id) from top?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to capture the CPU idle time (`id`) from `top`.

The following code captures Load Average and I am trying to manipulate the following code so that it capture's CPU idle time.

Any ideas welcome.

```s
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU load %: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

The above code outputs:

```
CPU load %: 0.44
```

I want to change the code so that it outputs CPU idle time

```
CPU Id %: 92.9%
```

Example Top output:

```
top - 10:35:25 up 1 day, 16:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.24, 0.16, 0.15
Tasks: 210 total,   2 running, 198 sleeping,  10 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.2 us,  0.2 sy,  4.7 ni, 92.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.1 st
KiB Mem:  16433064 total,  1353396 used, 15079668 free,   180944 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   700468 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
24293 ubuntu    30  10   32828   2576   1608 S  19.3  0.0   0:25.30 fiberlamp
 2173 ubuntu    20   0   51200  16496   4952 S   9.3  0.1 263:34.18 Xvnc4
12648 ubuntu    20   0   23668   1732   1180 R   0.3  0.0   0:04.25 top 
...
```

Comment: What's the output you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: Try to look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

Comment: The expected output is still unclear...

Comment: I hesitate to give an answer because, just for example, *my* line #3 in top looks like this (note the absence of "id" for idle, and the use of decimal comma instead of decimal point): `%Cpu(s):  0,0 be,  0,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 99,9 un,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
` -- the exact output of `top` may vary (depending on platform, locale etc.), and your capture line might come up empty.

Comment: Thanks for this.- I need to get it consistent across applications.

Comment: Expected Output -I'm trying to capture 92.9 id value from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep for '%Cpu(s)'

```
top -bn1 | grep '%Cpu(s)' | awk -F',' '{printf "CPU id %: %.2f%\n", $4}'
```

Comment: Add `LANG=en_US` to avoid decimal comma issues. And I am still not sure if you can authoritatively rely on "idle" being the fourth value in the line...

Comment: Hi, I'm unclear what you mean by Add LANG=en_US where should I do that please?

Comment: One thing with this solution is that the CPU metric seems to always return the same value. 94.5% However, when I run top in parallel I get CPU Idle with varying metrics