# Why does cpu load not change more than a few hundredths?

Tags: bash, cpu, cpu-load

I'm running this command

```
grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'
```

Yet it only outputs something like 0.99xxxx%

If I do an apt-get upgrade or any process, I would imagine it would go above 1%. Even running stress -c 1 doesn't make it change any.

Is there a way to log CPU usage accurately? Server has 1 vCPU.

Need to have this log every 5 seconds.

```
while sleep 5; do "code" >> logfile; done
```

Comment: what about `top`? Also you can use plain old `ps`

Comment: Not familiar with top or ps when using awk

Comment: `while (sleep 5); do` is much less efficient than `while sleep 5; do`, and for no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Anyhow -- did you check the value of `USER_HZ` on your system? It's not necessarily 1/100 of a second; on desktop systems, it's not at all unheard of to crank that up..

Comment: I'm also... very unclear on the reasoning behind your math. (cputime) * 100 / (cputime + iowait)? Why would you expect that to provide a useful result?

Comment: I thought $5 was idle?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy $5 is indeed idle, not iowait which is $6

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get overall CPU Usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

Answer (score 5):

> Why does cpu load not change more than a few hundredths?

Because `/proc/stat` is returning aggregated CPU load statistics since the system last booted, not real-time ones. If you run your script just after a reboot, the reported load might significantly change as long as the CPU load itself changes. However, the longer the script runs the lesser load changes will impact the displayed value and after a while, the value will essentially stay constant.

If you want to compute the load from `/proc/stat` and not use the already available tools that do it, you need to compute the difference from two consecutive samples, eg :

```
while sleep 5; do grep -w cpu /proc/stat ; done | \
    awk '{
        print (o2+o4-$2-$4)*100/(o2+o4+o5-$2-$4-$5) "%"
        o2=$2;o4=$4;o5=$5}'
```

Otherwise, a simpler but less accurate way might be:

```
vmstat -n 5 | \
    awk '{used=$13+$14;total=used+$15
          if(total>0) print used*100/total "%"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log the highest cpu percentage (this is, the process with the highest cpu usage in the moment of querying), you can use:

```
ps -e -o %cpu | tail -n +2 | sort -r | head -n 1 > cpu-usage.log
```

Explanation of the command:

- `ps -e -o %cpu` gives you process information of **e**very process in the **o**utput format that consist only in the cpu usage percentage
- `tail -n +2` filters the previous output starting from the second line (thus ignoring the header printed by `ps`)
- `sort -r` sort the values in reverse order (highest first)
- `head -n 1` filters the data returned by `sort` so you discard all but the first line

Comment: This seems to give more accurate results, however, how is it that I have 112% CPU with a single core?

Comment: Here you can find a nice explanation for that: http://serverfault.com/questions/522922/cpu-more-than-100-in-ps-aux

Comment: And here you can find more info http://superuser.com/questions/174660/why-is-the-cpu-usage-reported-by-top-in-linux-over-100

Comment: According to his/her code, the OP is looking for the whole CPU usage, not the usage of the (single) highest CPU consumer.

Comment: In that case the question should be flagged as duplicated and the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

Comment: @higuaro It might indeed. The OP is using exactly the same questionable code that was lately added to one of the most upvoted replies there though. If he picked the code from that reply, he should have read the last comment!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified #3 for my own uses:

```
for x in $(seq 1 11);do sleep 5;grep -w cpu /proc/stat ; done | \
awk '{
    print (o2+o4-$2-$4)*100/(o2+o4+o5-$2-$4-$5) "%"
    o2=$2;o4=$4;o5=$5}'
```

Where seq is the number of samples taken, Sleep is still the length of time between samples

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.