# Bash: wait until CPU usage gets below a threshold

Tags: linux, bash, cpu-usage

In a bash script I need to wait until CPU usage gets below a threshold.

In other words, I'd need a command `wait_until_cpu_low` which I would use like this:

```
# Trigger some background CPU-heavy command
wait_until_cpu_low 40
# Some other commands executed when CPU usage is below 40%
```

How could I do that?

Edit:

- target OS is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5
- I'm considering the average CPU usage (across all cores)

Comment: There are many posts that can help to get the current CPU usage. My approach would be to keep checking the usage after certain intervals and if the usage in not below threshold keep checking it and once its below the threshold, just to proceed with the rest of the code. I am not a bash coder. Please make me aware if I missed something important? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/how-to-get-cpu-usage-for-every-core-with-a-bash-script-using-standard-nix-tools

Comment: You could narrow this question down to a particular environment (eg, Linux or Solaris), which will drive the specific tool to use.  There is no standard POSIX way to get the CPU utilization.  Further, you should clarify what you mean by CPU: since modern CPU have multiple cores, do you consider these each CPU?  Do you want an average of the cores?  Do you want average across all CPUs' cores?

Comment: @bishop Thank you for the clarifications. See my edit.

Comment: `yum install sysstat`, then `mpstat -P ALL 1 | grep all | awk '{print $9}'` should get you in the ballpark of the idle % on all CPU.  That said, you could also clarify the question by specifying whether the threshold is percentage "idle" or "used".

Comment: Adding a small code sample outlining the context you want to use this in, however contrived, might help to dissuade down voters (just something I've noticed with this type of question)

Comment: @Clive I've added an example of code sample. Hope the question will be reopened.

Comment: I would also like to answer, but unfortunately the question is closed. (Good job!) I would use `top` and `awk` to get the value: `usage=$(top -n1 | awk 'NR==3{print $2}'`. Then use `bc` to compare the value against a threshold: `if bc -l <<< "$usage < $thres"  ; then echo "usage below thres"; fi` .. Put that into a loop and make a function out of it.

Comment: @hek2mgl Shall I re-post it as a new question? (there has been many edits since the original submission)

Comment: @fiddler I would wait a bit. It should take at maximum a few hours until it is re-opened (just one additional vote is missing)..

Comment: **Question:** what do you mean by 40% CPU usage?  On most Unix systems, having more that the one CPU means the maximum CPU usage is `100% * NumCPUs`.  So is that 40% meaning "40% of maximum CPU usage" or "40% as the system reports it"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wait_for_cpu_usage()
{
    current=$(mpstat 1 1 | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print int(100 - $12 + 0.5) }')
    while [[ "$current" -ge "$1" ]]; do
        current=$(mpstat 1 1 | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print int(100 - $12 + 0.5) }')
        sleep 1
    done
}
```

Notice it requires sysstat package installed.

Comment: `current` is evaluated only once, right? Shouldn't it be recomputed inside the loop?

Comment: Actually, current is not evaluated only once, the problem is that I forgot to update current status, so you are right

Comment: `line 4: [[: 6.67: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".67")`

Comment: Oops, I've forgotten to round the output. Check now

Comment: Value of `current` is always 7 (I added an `echo` in the script), even when doing some CPU-intensive stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88384/discussion-between-fmbesteiro-and-fiddler).

Comment: That said -- `$12` is `gnice` on my mpstat build. Is that the number we want?

Comment: If $12 is gnice then you need to replace 12 by idle's column number, or check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229699/2980812 which is a good workaround too

Comment: This will return true if mpstat reports 10.4% but the threshold is at 10. I had my reasons to use `bc`. The fact that an additional program needs to get installed to obtain information that is already there makes the solution even worse.

Comment: That was done on purpose, you can play with the plus 0.5 to change that, by simply removing it, for example

atm its like 10.4 -> 10
10.7 -> 11
9.7 -> 10

without it: 10,4 -> 11
10.1 -> 11
and so on

Comment: i got error by running it using `bash`
:
`./wait.sh: line 6: [[: 53\n 53: syntax error in expression (error token is "53")`

Comment: My `$current` variable contains two number seperated by space. I fix it by adding `| { read first rest ; echo $first ; }` after awk filter

Answer (score 11):

A much more efficient version just calls `mpstat` and `awk` once each, and keeps them both running until done; no need to explicitly `sleep` and restart both processes every second (which, on an embedded platform, could add up to measurable overhead):

```
wait_until_cpu_low() {
    awk -v target="$1" '
    $13 ~ /^[0-9.]+$/ {
      current = 100 - $13
      if(current <= target) { exit(0); }
    }' < <(LC_ALL=C mpstat 1)
}
```

I'm using `$13` here because that's where `idle %` is for my version of mpstat; substitute appropriately if yours differs.

This has the extra advantage of doing floating point math correctly, rather than needing to round to integers for shell-native math.

Comment: Brilliant!! Saved my day. Thanks Charles:)

Comment: This script worked perfectly, until under certain mysterious circumstances involving gitlab-runner, mpstat appears to ignore the Broken Pipe when awk exits, and keeps running. Using strace showed every write is returning EPIPE. Just commenting as a warning in case someone else has this problem.

Comment: @szmoore, I'd suggest filing a ticket to get this fixed in `mpstat`; it really _should_ consider that error fatal. That said, if you need a workaround in bash for this, I think it should be possible to build one if you have a version of the shell new enough for process substitutions to store their PID in `$!` (I think that feature was introduced in 4.3, maybe?) -- if you ask a new question on the subject, feel free to @ me in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I had a really hard time reproducing the issue outside of a gitlab-runner environment. I suspected gitlab-runner blocked the `SIGPIPE` signal somehow but didn't have time to prove who I should be filing the bug report against.
For my use case I rewrote the script in Python using `psutil` instead, so it's unfortunately no longer a `bash` question.

Answer (score 4):

You might use a function based on the `top` utility. But note, that doing so is not very reliable because the CPU utilization might - rapidly - change at any time. Meaning that just because the check succeeded, it is not guaranteed that the CPU utilization will stay low as long the following code runs. You have been warned.

The function:

```
function wait_for_cpu_usage {
    threshold=$1
    while true ; do
        # Get the current CPU usage
        usage=$(top -n1 | awk 'NR==3{print $2}' | tr ',' '.')

        # Compared the current usage against the threshold
        result=$(bc -l <<< "$usage <= $threshold")
        [ $result == "1" ] && break

        # Feel free to sleep less than a second. (with GNU sleep)
        sleep 1
    done
    return 0
}

# Example call
wait_for_cpu_usage 25
```

Note that I'm using `bc -l` for the comparison since top prints the CPU utilization as a float value.

Comment: I get an error. `top -n1 | awk 'NR==3{print $2}'` returns `6.2%us,`

Comment: Which version of top and awk are you using?

Comment: top: 3.2.8, awk: 3.1.7

Comment: Hard to reproduce for me. You basically will need to remove the `%us` - which should not be there at all. Find out what's causing this (missing whitespace in top's output etc..) and fix the awk command according to this. (hint: `-F[ %]+` should do the trick). My `top-3.3.9` and `GNU awk-4.1.1` are simply working.

Comment: Maybe try `uptime`?  `uptime | awk '{ gsub(/,/, ""); print $10; }'`

Comment: @Mr.Llama `uptime` shows the *load*, not the CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by "Mr. Llama" in a comment above, I've used uptime to write my simple function:

```sh
function wait_cpu_low() {
  threshold=$1
  while true; do
    current=$(uptime | awk '{ gsub(/,/, ""); print $10 * 100; }')
    if [ $current -lt $threshold ]; then
      break;
    else
      sleep 5
    fi
  done
}
```

In awk expression:

- `$10` is to get average CPU usage in last minute
- `$11` is to get average CPU usage in last 5 minutes
- `$12` is to get average CPU usage in last 15 minutes

And here is an usage example:

```sh
wait_cpu_low 20
```

It waits one minute average CPU usage is below 20% of one core of CPU.

Comment: I like this script the most. One fix:  `print $11` needs to be used instead of `print $10` which always throws zero on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Another fix: You may want to put some `sleep 60` as the first command in the function; otherwise the function would end immediately if launched simultaneously with some CPU-intensive task (due to load value being averaged).