# How to remove % from output in shell command

Tags: bash, shell, command, cpu-usage

I found this command in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux).

According to the command

```
top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f%%\n", prefix, 100 - v }'
```

I got the result is such as 2.9%.

I would like to remove % when output. Which part is printing **%** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
top -b -n2 -p 1 | fgrep "Cpu(s)" | tail -1 | awk -F'id,' -v prefix="$prefix" '{ split($1, vs, ","); v=vs[length(vs)]; sub("%", "", v); printf "%s%.1f\n", prefix, 100 - v }'
```

I've removed the last `%%` in the `printf`.

Comment: Ohh, yeah, That's what I want. Thanks @FredMaggiowski