# How to find CPU load in linux and use grep command for same?

Tags: c, linux, grep

```
**Without grep**

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    long double a[4], b[4], loadavg;
    FILE *fp;
    char dump[50];

    for(;;)
    {
        fp = fopen("/proc/stat","r");
        fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
        fclose(fp);
        sleep(1);

        fp = fopen("/proc/stat","r");
        fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf",&b[0],&b[1],&b[2],&b[3]);
        fclose(fp);

        loadavg = ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])) / ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]));
        printf("The current CPU utilization is : %Lf\n",loadavg);
    }
    return(0);
 }
```

I have tried this, but It is not showing correct result and It also not have grep command. I have found other solutions also, but all are showing wrong answer. I am not able to found Direct command also. If anyone have any idea then suggest me same.

Comment: I suggest to use `/proc/loadavg`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get overall CPU Usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

Comment: uptime | awk '/load average/ {printf("%s",($10+$11+$12))}'

Comment: Is this Correct?