# Get each core usage BASH

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I would like to listen to the CPU usage, by getting each core percentage usage: `CPUcore1` and `CPUcore2` in a loop.

```
while :
do
    if [ $CPUcore1 -gt 95 ] && [ $CPUcore2 -gt 95 ]
    then
        //script..
    fi
done
```

`CPUcore1` and `CPUcore2` should be equal to what present on `htop`

[image]

In this example:

`CPUcore1`=70.0

`CPUcore2`=44.4

I know that some calculation should be made in order to evaluate this.

Comment: You could use [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). BTW, processes are migrated by the kernel from one core to another

Comment: In `[ ... ]`, you have to escape `>`, or it is interpreted as redirection, creating a file `95`.

Comment: Fun fact: the command `[ $CPUcore1 > 95 ]` is semantically identical to `test $CPUcore > 95` and `> 95 test $CPUcore1` and `test > 95 $CPUcore1` and `[ > 95 $CPUcore1 ]` and `[ $CPUcore1 ] > 95`

Comment: Use `if [ "$CPUcore1" -gt 95 ] && [ "$CPUcore2" -gt 95 ]`

Comment: Escaping the `\>` is not what you want, since that will do a lexical comparison rather than a numeric comparison.

Comment: LOL I get it,
But thats not my question, I need the `CPUcore1` and `CPUcore2` calc..

Comment: It's hard to keep up with the edits!  `( $CPUcore1 > 95 )` is also not what you want, since that will run the command `$CPUcore1` in a subhsell and redirect its output to a file named `95`.

Comment: I used to JS, but thats not my question..
I need the calc as mentioned, the rest is searchable and easy to fix LOL

Answer (score 0):

`>` is never what you want to compare numeric values.  When it is a comparison operator, it is a lexical comparison rather than a numeric comparison. (so 2 > 10).  Often, it's not a comparison operator, but a file redirect.

With `test "$a" -gt "$b"`, `$a` and `$b` must be integers, and the string `70.0` is not an integer.  Floating point arithmetic is ugly in the shell, so it's probably best to do it in awk with something like:

```
if awk -v a="$CPUcore1" -v b="$CPUcore2" 'BEGIN{exit !(a > 95 && b > 95)}'; then
        ...
fi
```

Comment: I told u, thats not what I asked and yet you answered!
Now no one will answer me since there is an answer..

Comment: @iTaMaR I don't understand your comment.  You are attempting to do integer comparisons of non-integer values.  If that's not the problem, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Ah....I see. ..

Comment: This code I posted was  just an example for the wrapper of the variables I need, I need `CPUcore1` and  `CPUcore2` calculations so that they will be equal to the usage of each core

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux