# How to calculate %CPU of a process on a multicore linux server

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, top-command

On a multicore linux server(54 cores), we are running services in docker container. In particular, am looking for how to calculate %CPU of a process using the %CPU value captured from TOP command for a specific process and calculate and assert if that process %CPU is beyond a user defined threshold say 75%.

For e.g, below are two process details captured from top command.

7180 user1  20   0 9855556   1.0g   9012 S   2100  6.4 332:06.06 java -cp /apps/service1 - %CPU is 2100 - here the %CPU is exceeding 100 i.e. it is using more than 1 core out of 54

6594 user1  20   0 7124652 235912   6888 S   0.7  1.5 272:53.89 java -cp /apps/service2 - %CPU is 0.7 - here the %CPU is 0.7

So, my requirement is to get the %CPU and calculate 75% threshold and then assert if 75% value with %CPU.

Threshold calculation,

threshold * total_core / 100 = 75 * 54 /100 = 40.5

And, getting %CPU from TOP command of a particular process and then, if it exceeding more than 100 then divide by 100 and then asserting with above threshold value.
And, if it is below 100 then directly asserting with above threshold value.

Am not sure, this is correct. But out of my search in google and other places. I got the above and trying. But would like to conform from one of the experts from stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear from the question as written what exactly is being asked here. Are you asking how to calculate the `pcpu` value of `top` yourself, i.e. how to query the OS directly? Are you asking if you must handle the unit of pcpu, i.e.  whether top outputs percentage of all CPU, percentage per CPU, or fractional usage? Are you asking whether the formula matches your prose? Relatedly, what do you consider %CPU - the instantaneous or lifetime efficiency per machine or per core?

Comment: `top` or just about any %CPU calculation gives you 100% per core. So if you have 54 cores, you have a total of 5400% to show 100% utilization. So if you are reading 2100% CPU, you are using ~39% of the total you have available. If I understand your question, your threshold would then be `.75 * 5400` or `4050`.

Comment: yes, @DavidC.Rankin I was looking for something close to above. And, more clearly, if a process %CPU value from TOP command can be directly evaluated with .75*5400 and if exceeds can we say that specific process is using more than 75% of total cpu? And, suppose if a process %CPU is just in single digits like 5.3, even in this case 0.75 * 5400 can be checked (manually if we see 5.3 it is clearly not using much %CPU). But through script we need to go for a standard calculation right in that sense. Evn for process reporting single digits evaluating with 0.75 *5400 should be standard right? Thanks

Comment: There is some discussion in the question and many answers to [How to get overall CPU usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229333/3422102). The issue is computing the per-process use. You really want to look at [Calculate the Total CPU Usage of a Process From /proc/pid/stat](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/total-process-cpu-usage) which should have all the information you need. You will get the total used by any process and compare to your `.75 * 5400` threshold.