# Get Current Process CPU Usage Linux C

Tags: c++, linux, cpu

I'd like to get the specific CPU Usage of a process under Linux in C++.
However, apart from reading

```
/proc/stat
```

I don't know how to do that.

If I read this file, then I don't know how I can't get the CPU usage of my current process when I launch the program ...

I want to get the CPU usage of the program I'm running, do you have any clue on how to do it ?
I've seen complex solution on the site and I haven't understood them all ... I just need a direction.

It seems my /proc/pid/stat file isn't changing after sleep(2), is that normal ?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux

Comment: Notice that there are a lot of directories in `/proc` that are named as a number? They are the same as all process identifiers running, and each directory contain lots of files with information about that specific process.

Comment: How abt this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-c?rq=1

Comment: But ... there's something I don't understand in those topics. Does /proc/stat contains the CPU usage of my CURRENT process ?

Comment: @Mike: `/proc/<pid>/stat`

Comment: `double getcurrusage() { for (int i=0; i<1000000000;++i); return 1.0; }`

Comment: Do you mean the usage as a percentage or as the cpu time you have used.

Comment: Both. I mean both. I've tryed the solution given by first comment. However in my file "/proc/pid/stat", after the sleep(2), the data don't change ... is that normal ? I can't calculate CPU usage if it doesn't change ... do you know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the times system call, which gives the time spent by the CPU on a given process. Try this tutorial, [Linux process execution time](http://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/linux-process-execution-time).