# How to calculate GPU Load

Tags: linux, load, cpu, gpu

I want to calculate the GPU load but have no idea which file contains that. Is it also stored somewhere like the CPU load in the /proc/loadavg file ?

Comment: @fedorqui Eh? @Hellboy `/proc/loadavg` does *not* contain the CPU load.

Comment: It contains the load for the last 1min, 5 mins and 15 mins.

Comment: Exactly, the system load. But not the CPU load.

Comment: So, where can I find the CPU and GPU load ?
Do we have to calculate the CPU load from the /proc/stat file under the label cpu (which contain various jiffies) ?

Comment: The CPU load is not stored in any file, it has to be calculated. Because at a specific point in time the CPU (core) load is either idle or at 100%. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-c) on how to calculate it or just use the output from `top`.

Comment: Are CPU load and CPU usage different things or the same ?

Comment: Please note that this is *not* a place for discussions. They are the same.

Answer (score 4):

For nVidia gpus see the thread: [checking GPU load on nVidia hardware? [solved]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107117)

For intel chips just type:

```
su -c 'intel_gpu_top'
```

on the command line.

Comment: The GPU I am using is SGX-544