# Is there any linux function call to get CPU usage for a specific thread by passing thread ID?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Is there any direct linux function call to get CPU usage in run time for a specific thread by passing thread ID? 
If not function call, is there any other possible way to achieve the same?

I have an application written in c which is running on a linux platform. And it has multi threads running in parallel. In which i need to identify the CPU usage of each thread. For that i need to enhance my code with a system call which gives me the CPU usage for a specific thread. Consider i have all the thread IDs in a structure ready in the run time.

Comment: I think this link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-c

Answer (score 1):

You can get CPU usage of specific process as follows

```
 ps -p <pid> -o %cpu
```

You can descard `%CPU` word from output like

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu | tail -n +2
```

You can pass above command in system call as well.

Also look function for getting current process utilization named [getusage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the amount and depth of information you are looking for, if you want to make relatively simple estimates of what each thread is doing you can look at [pthread_getcpulockid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html).  You use the thread IDs you have saved to get the per thread clockid and then use the clockids to call `clock_gettime` for each thread.  There is nice little example program of this right on the man page.

Otherwise I think you are headed into /proc territory.