# how to monitor cpu utilisation of a specific application in UNIX server

Tags: unix

tried with top command

> `top | grep <process name>`

but the cpu percent changes ferequently .Moreover, if I compare the value with a monitoring tool which refreshes every five minutes it differs from it

tried with

```
ps -o %cpu -p <pid>
```

..but still no help

Comment: ps -o %cpu shows the cpu usage for the lifetime of the process. Your monitoring tool might just show the CPU usage averaged over 5 minutes - you should figure out how your particular monitoring tool works. You can slow down top to average e.g. every 10 seconds by running top -d 10 , or 5 minutes by doing `top -d 300`. Since the CPU usage of the last 10 seconds or last 5 minutes are not stored anywhere, you'll have to wait 10 seconds or 5 minutes for the initial proper value.

Answer (score -1):

This is already answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16736599/4004007

> ## Preparation
>
> To calculate CPU usage for a specific process you'll need the
>   following:
>
> 1. [`/proc/uptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)
>
>    - `#1` uptime of the system (seconds)
> 2. [`/proc/[PID]/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)
>
>    - `#14` `utime` - CPU time spent in user code, measured in *clock ticks*
>    - `#15` `stime` - CPU time spent in kernel code, measured in *clock ticks*
>    - `#16` `cutime` - **Waited-for children's** CPU time spent in user code (in *clock ticks*)
>    - `#17` `cstime` - **Waited-for children's** CPU time spent in kernel code (in *clock ticks*)
>    - `#22` `starttime` - Time when the process started, measured in *clock ticks*
> 3. Hertz (number of clock ticks per second) of your system.
>
>    - In most cases, [`getconf CLK_TCK`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getconf.html)
>        can be used to return the number of clock ticks.
>    - The [`sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html)
>        C function call may also be used to return the hertz value.
>
> ---
>
> ## Calculation
>
> First we determine the total time spent for the process:
>
> ```
> total_time = utime + stime
>  We also have to decide whether we want to include the time from children processes. If we do, then we add those values to
> ```
>
> `total_time`:
>
> ```
> total_time = total_time + cutime + cstime
> ```
>
> Next we get the total elapsed time in *seconds* since the process
>   started:
>
> ```
> seconds = uptime - (starttime / Hertz)
> ```
>
> Finally we calculate the CPU usage percentage:
>
> ```
> cpu_usage = 100 * ((total_time / Hertz) / seconds)
> ```
>
> #### See also
>
> > [Top and ps not showing the same cpu result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58541)
> >
> > [How to get total cpu usage in Linux (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017438/1806289)
> >
> > [Calculating CPU usage of a process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424556/1806289)

Comment: @kanchan: I'm glad that it worked for you, marking the answer as correct will help others who might have the same question.